What is the correct type annotation for "bytes or bytearray"?
In Python 3.11 or newer, is there a more convenient type annotation to use than bytes | bytearray for a function argument that means "An ordered collection of bytes"? It seems wasteful to require constructing a bytes from a bytearray (or the other way around) just to satisfy the type-checker.
Note that the function does not mutate the argument; it's simply convenient to pass bytes or bytearray instances from different call sites.
e.g.
def serialize_to_stream(stream: MyStream, data: bytes | bytearray) -> None:
    for byte in data:
        stream.accumulate(byte)

(This example is contrived, of course, but the purpose is to show that data is only read, never mutated).

Can't you just use bytes annotation? What's the issue?

Why not be less specific? From what you've shown any iterable of things your stream can accumulate would work.

Oh, cool, I didn't realize that bytearray was compatible with the bytes type from a type-annotation perspective.

@wim The issue is that this behaviour was deprecated by PEP 688.

I think PEP 688 also provides the answer (for Python 3.12+, at least): use collections.abc.Buffer.

This question is similar to: Bytes-like object or Buffer type annotaion. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The typing module used to have a type to represent this: ByteString. However, it was deprecated in 3.9.
From the same section:

Prefer collections.abc.Buffer, or a union like bytes | bytearray | memoryview.

